# Stop Print Screen saving to Imgur.com on Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, imgur

For as long as I have been using computers I have used the 'Print Screen' button on my keyboard to take a screen shot and copy it to the clip board. I could then paste the screenshot into a document or the canvas of a image editing program.

Now when I press print screen it makes a camera sound and opens up my screenshot to an external website https://i.imgur.com...

I am not sure how this has happened, but it happened months ago and when I have had time I have searched for how to turn this off and revert back to only copying to my clipboard. But I have not been able to find any explanation of how this happened or how to turn it off? I can't believe I am on the only one who is struggling with this.

I am able to press the `Windows` key and `Print Screen` key to copy screen to the clipboard.

Question is: How do I remove this link to imgur completely?

I have tried looking at the registry to see if I can work something out as I saw this stackoverflow.com/questions/28083031/… and this related stackoverflow.com/questions/55490965/…

I can confirm that I don't have ImgurSnipper app installed, nor any other apps that I can find that has caused this to happen.

Comment: check who's stealing your print screen key using the way described here [How to find out what program took over control over Print Screen key?](https://superuser.com/q/951131/241386)

Comment: @phuclv, unfortunately, this will not help him since those types of programs do not work - and may cause issues - in Windows 8 and higher (see here one such warning https://superuser.com/a/1134110/368970 but it is all over)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The program that is doing this is ShareX. It may well be an excellent app, but for now I have uninstalled it and I have my Print Screen key back as it was; Copying a screenshot to the clipboard.

I found it as I was prompted that an update was available and so took a closer look and suddenly realised that this was what had taken over. I don't know how or when it was installed, perhaps it came bundled with something else, or I installed it myself. I can not remember.

Comment: this is the answer that really works and SUPIDLY SIMPLE to execute... everything other answer is not good....

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have have inadvertently installed [ImgurSniper](https://mrousavy.github.io/ImgurSniper/).

1. Right click your start button -> Choose apps and features (at the top)
2. Check your apps and features and uninstall from there.
3. Reboot and take a "print screen".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alas, it's a good suggestion, but I have been through all my apps and checked for this, and had a check of other apps that might have this within it and I haven't found anything. I have tried looking at the registry to see if I can work something out as I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083031/disable-the-printscreen-keyboard-option-from-windows and this related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490965/steps-to-enable-the-print-screen-key-using-edit-registry-in-window-10 that I thought might point me in the right direction. I'll keep trying to work it out

Comment: @MartinHügi, while it might not be ImgurSnipper then it is another such type of program (Greenshot, ShareX, etc), that is absolutely certain (Windows itself cannot do this.) Possible to post a list/screenshot of all installed programs?

Comment: @MartinHügi you dont happen to have an imgur extension installed? Specifically imgur Community Extension?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imgur-community-extension/ehoopddfhgaehhmphfcooacjdpmbjlao?hl=en-US

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Windows Explorer and go to Pictures. You will find the Screenshots folder there. It is the default location and if you have never taken any screenshot, then the folder will not be created.
2. Right click on the Screenshots folder and go to Properties.
3. Under the Location tab, you will find the default save location. Click on Move. Now choose the the folder where you want to change the default location. Tap on Select Folder. The folder location will be moved to the new location set by you.

I am guessing this is where your imgur issue is. Let me know if this helps.

[Reference](https://mywindowshub.com/how-to-change-the-default-save-location-for-screenshots-in-windows-10/)

Comment: That is certainly not what he's experiencing, since - let's even say Imgur has an option to have a folder on the PC - it opens an online link with his image.

Comment: However, thanks MLG I have looked at the reference you linked to and I have seen that if I press the Windows Key and then Print Screen it saves the screenshot to my clipboard and doesn't send it to imgur. So in a way even though you haven't answered my question directly my problem is solved as long as I remember the Windows key. Although I still do not know how the imgur link has come from or is this just normal for Windows 10 ??

Comment: Glad I could help. Even indirectly.